# How to override the django admin translation?

Tags: python, django, localization, internationalization, django-admin

I'm trying to override the default translations of Django's admin site.

I'm using Django 1.6. My `settings.py` contains:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# ...

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'nl'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
LOCALE_PATHS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "locale"),)
```

I have copied the file `django/contrib/admin/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES/django.po` to `my_project/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES/django.po` and I've made some changes to it.

Next, I have run `python manage.py compilemessages` and `python manage.py runserver`.

When I visit `localhost:8000/admin`, however, I'm still seeing Django's default admin translations. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit - I found the problem:**

The above description is the correct way to override app translations. I followed my own instructions and they work. The reason for my problem was that I accidentally omitted the `nl` subdirectory the first time. I am a dumb person.

Comment: Did you restart your development server? In my experience, translation files are aggressively cached

Comment: I restarted the development server and I've deployed the code. Still ignoring my translations :-(

Comment: Do you mean you deleted the 'nl' subdirectory?

Comment: side note, django 1.6 is no longer supported for a long time now. You should consider upgrading to 2.2

Comment: @hedgie could you write up an answer and accept it yourself to close this question?

Comment: Since you found the solution, you might consider answering your own question as a benefit to other users.

Comment: hello, LANGUAGE_CODE = 'nl' is wrong. you should add the full locale nl-NL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm providing an answer, even though @hedgie mostly answered their own question. I'll add a bit of context and description of what's happening. This answer is still applicable as of Django 3.0.

Just as you can override a Django-provided admin template by duplicating the template's name and directory structure within our own project, you can override Django-provided admin translations by duplicating a `.po` file's name and directory structure within our project.

Django's admin translations live in `django/contrib/admin/locale/` and are organized by language in directories named `[language code]/LC_MESSAGES/`. These individual language directories contain two `.po` files, `django.po` and `djangojs.po`, and their respective compiled `.mo` files. You will be overriding the `.po` files, and compiling our own `.mo` files.

The first thing you have to do is enable translations in settings, and tell Django where you store our translation files.

**settings.py**

```py
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# ...

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'nl-NL'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
LOCALE_PATHS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "locale"),)  # our custom translations will go here
```

Note that although the directory Django uses is `nl`, the full language identifier for Dutch in the Netherlands is `nl-NL`. You can find a full list of identifiers organized by country [here](http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html).

Next, you'll mimic Django's directory structure and create two files in a new directory:

`my_project/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES/django.po`

`my_project/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES/djangojs.po`

Note that this path must also match what you provided in `settings.py`.

Copy and paste the contents of [Django's translation files](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/admin/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES). You can now edit the translations for whichever strings you like. For example:

**django.po**

```
msgid "Are you sure?"
--- msgstr "Weet u het zeker?"
+++ msgstr "Weet u het zeker?!"
```

Now you need to compile the messages with:

`python manage.py compilemessages`

This command compiles your `.po` files into `.mo` files, which Django will use to translate any matching gettext calls. You should now see your custom translations in the admin interface.

Comment: Awesome! Just a note: No need to `Copy and paste the contents of Django's translation files`. The new file seems to be merged with the existing .po files.

Answer (score 0):

I know this old, In my case, I want to change the 'Authentication and Authorization' app name. This is how I achieved it.

1. Run the command, `python manage.py makemessages -l en`

   Note: This command will generate a `.po` file in the `locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/` directory.

   Before running this command, make sure you have set the locale directory path first in your `setting.py`, mine looks like this: `LOCALE_PATHS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "locale"),)`
2. Open the `django.po`, delete everything in it, and add these lines,

   ```
   #: contrib/auth/apps.py:16
   msgid "Authentication and Authorization"
   msgstr "User Authentication"
   ```

   Note: In my case, I am renaming the `Authentication and Authorization` app name of the auth model
3. Run the command `python manage.py compilemessages` to compile the translations.
   Note: This will generate the corresponding .mo file.
4. Restart your Django

I hope this will help others.