# Change name of the "Authentication and Authorization" menu in Django/python

Tags: python, django, admin

I'm learning python/Django and setting up my first project. All is going well but I've been searching like crazy on something very simple.

There is a default menu item "Authentication and Authorization" and I want to change the name. I've searched in the template if I need to extend something, I've searched if there's a `.po` file or what not but I can't find it nor a hint on which parameter I should overwrite in `admin.py` to set it.

I'm not trying to install multi language or some advanced localization, just want to change the name of that one menu item :)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom `AppConfig` pointing to original `django.auth` module and override `verbose_name`. Then use your custom `AppConfig` in `INSTALLED_APPS` instead of original `auth` app.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/applications/#configuring-applications

Comment: Could you give us more details about this approach?

Answer (score 3):

To follow up on [Lorenzo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39213750/4812260) (Django 3.0):

Create a file with your custom AppConfig somewhere in your project

```
# 'authconfig.py'
from django.apps import AppConfig

class CustomAuthConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'django.contrib.auth'
    verbose_name = 'my super special auth name'
```

Then, in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    #'django.contrib.auth', # comment out to avoid duplicate apps
    'authconfig.CustomAuthConfig', # add this in for custom config of auth module
    ...
]
```

Comment: I used a similar method to this and django migration stops syncing model permissions.

Comment: I suspect some previous maintainers on a project I contribute to found this answer and blindly did this, because I came along and no permissions existed, because this is a hard replace.

The way I got around that is to `from django.contrib.auth.apps import AuthConfig`, then subclass that, which preserves the `ready` method that populates permissions.

Django 3.2 for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom locale (refer to [How to override the django admin translation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873972/how-to-override-the-django-admin-translation)) then the best way is to add these lines to the django.po file:

```
msgid "Authentication and Authorization"
msgstr "Your text for the auth app"
```

For some reason many localization files fail to include a translation for the "Authentication and Authorization" string. Adding it like that (and using the compilemessages command as mentioned in the link above) should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to do this without creating a custom app or using translation is to just add this line to any of the apps registered after `django.contrib.auth`

```
from django.contrib.auth.apps import AuthConfig

AuthConfig.verbose_name = "Your favourite name"
```

This basically overwrites the verbose name of AuthConfig after its declared in `settings.py`

Answer (score -1):

This can't be done at least cleanly via templates..

You can put the auth app verbose name "authentication and authorization" in your own .po file (& follow Django docs on translation)
This way Django will normally use your name.